# Updating Table with New Lines

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup, lookup-tables, vba

I have a 3500+ row table that each week 250 old lines are removed and 250 new lines are added, say on a Sunday. Throughout the course of the week, columns Y and Z are used to write comments (Y via a drop down box). These comments are to stay with the associated row.

My problem is updating the table with the new 250 lines. The new lines will be released as a new table (so mixed amongst the 3000 rows that are not removed). Previously I copied all the data into another worksheet, performed a vlookup and then copy and pasted over the old table. Is there a better or quicker way? Open to using VBA/Macros.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes you can use VBA for this.  Are you having a specific problem using it?

Comment: I think I can be able to work out the VBA for the current way I update. What I am looking for is the code to search new lines only and add these. Copying and pasting all the data is pretty slow

Comment: What about copying all the data across and running a macro to remove duplicates? Is there a way to remove the duplicates from the bottom up so to speak thus leaving the original in place?

Comment: You can loop over the new file and use Find or Match to see if they're in the old file.  If not, copy them over.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Remove Duplicates feature in Excel on the Data tab.
This feature, allowing one to choose which column to use as the comparison factor is easiest.

If you need to write a macro, there are faster ways to code it than looping through 3000+ values to look for a duplicate or using FIND to locate duplicates.
I had a similar problem and wrote a macro to eliminate duplicates using a loop for 2000+ rows of data. It took 2 minutes to execute. The method referenced below took 2 seconds to execute!
Check out Rick Rothstein's code at 
[Fast Duplicate Check For Large Data Sets Using VBA](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/574917-fast-duplicate-check-large-data-sets-using-vba.html)
I used and modified his code and it is the fastest solution I have found.